# Crystal Reports with VS 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am en Error while generating report on my VPS server (Win 2008 64 bit). The project is working fine on my local pc with VS 2008. I have tried re-installing crystal, recompiling for x86 CPU and enabling 32 bit applications in application pool settings. Still no luck.

The error screen is as follows:

An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[LoadSaveReportException: An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5472; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5474

Comment: what version of crystal report is installed on your server

Comment: This sounds like it could be an access rights issue. To verify that. try running the web site with a local administrator account under Directory Security in IIS.

Answer (score -1):

Install `CRRedist2008_x86.msi` on your web server.

Depending on the version you're using, there may be a copy on your local PC at

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5`

That's it!.